# FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 26: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App

Tags: php, laravel-5

My team work get those errors when they try to testing our system which build in 
Laravel5.0 and install in Xampp.

FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 26: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App

```
FatalErrorException in Handler.php line 26: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tgofinance\tgofinance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tgofinance\tgofinance\app\Exceptions\Handler.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Tgofinance\tgofinance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
thrown
```

This is our PHP info[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation occur when laravel project version not compatible or not configured with your local installed version 
So the laravel not tracking the exact error and instead of showing exact error on line shows that type of errors

Creating sample project that making  changing with that may fix the problem.

See also: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39638065/7968316