# Try catch not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

Started working in Laravel 5.4 recently. I tried to catch an error and return an json response from controller in following code but it seems throwing error usual

```
try {
    $credentials = $request->only('Username', 'Password');
    $driverdata = Driver::where('username', $credentials['Username'])
            ->where('password', Hasher::hash($credentials['Password']))
            ->where('deleted', 0)
            ->where('blocked', 0)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->first();
    // if(!count($driverdata)){
    //  return response()->json("Login Failed",401);
    // }                        
    return response()->json($driverdata->toArray());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
}
```

I also tried

```
use Exception;
```

on top
also using as

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
}
```

Following is the error i get

> FatalErrorException in LoginController.php line 26:
>       Call to a member function toArray() on null

Any suggestions? But the same thing used to work in Laravel 5.2

Comment: what is exact error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry updated question @RahmanQaiser

Comment: `FatalErrorException` will not be catched in php.

Comment: rather you can manually deal with current scenerio
 if($driverdata){
    return response()->json($driverdata->toArray());
}
 return response()->json(['success' => false , 'error' => 'not found']);

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions didnt know that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39638065/4916265  PHP Verson you use?

Comment: @RahmanQaiser i did apply that condition, but i was curious why i couldnt catch it

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions PHP Version is 5.6.25

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592400/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-null)

Comment: Lets better fix your problem _Call to a member function toArray() on null_: you have to add again a condition like you commented out. `$driverdata` must be an object in Line 26. The removed code part checks that and returns...

Answer (score -2):

To fix your problem *Call to a member function toArray() on null* change:

```
 // if(!count($driverdata)){
 //  return response()->json("Login Failed",401);
 // }
```

to

```
 if(!count($driverdata)){
    //return response()->json("Login Failed",401);
    throw new Exception('Login Failed');
 }
```

This fixes also the current *FatalErrorException*

For the rest google: *laravel 5.4 fatalerrorexception php 5.6*

Comment: sorry i was away.. why throw an error when i can find that if $driverdata is empty. I was just curious to catch and identify the fatal errors

Comment: @KarthikNk Basicly this was to prevent the FatalError, because you use the `$driverdata` untested. And if `$driverdata` is `null` you get FatalError. So i posted an test here. If you throw an error at this point or not is on you. And you can at this point better handle an normal Exception as an FatalErrorException. I dont know how good you devleop so i give a simple solution. A have to ask: Why are parts commentd of your code? Because this allowes the code to throw an FatalError. If you uncomment this, you will no more get an Error. From where comes the downvote!?  Recheck the code logic.

Comment: well that proves the point, but i was looking for an direct catch instead of a manual throw. But yes as mentioned FatalErrorException cant be catched. Btw i didnt downvote TBH